# Display the return received from a POST request

Tags: javascript

I'm using vanilla javascript to create a `POST` request to my Flask App. I have a validation check when a user tries to sign up with an existing username. I send a 406 status back along with "Error": "Username already taken."

My question is, how do I get that error message to display on my frontend from a `POST` request?

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: e.target.username.value,
    friend_code: parseInt(e.target.friend_code.value),
    dark_mode: null,
    theme: null,
    avatar: null,
    created_at: null,
  }),
});
```

Comment: you may use `response.statusText` ; `response` being the object passed as a parameter when chaining `fetch` with `then` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Promise then in the first then block check the `status` property of response and if it's 406 then display error if you're using async await than try to read `status` property from your response variable.

something like this promise example

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: e.target.username.value,
    friend_code: parseInt(e.target.friend_code.value),
    dark_mode: null,
    theme: null,
    avatar: null,
    created_at: null,
  }),
})
.then(response => {
 if (response.status === 406) {
   // your display logic 
 } else {
   // other logic
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a similar response -> http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e90c0443300009200e9cc52

```
{
 "message":"Username already taken"   
}
```

and sent it with 406 status.

In order to get the message , i did `res=> res.json()` to return another promise and then `res.message` to get the message

```
  fetch("http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e90c0443300009200e9cc52")
    .then(res=> res.json())
    .then(res=> console.log(res.message))
    .catch(err=> console.log(err))
```

In your case `res.Error`